# Matplotlib Error: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'resampled'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was running this in my jupyter notebook,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap

# Color map
top = mpl.colormaps['Oranges_r'].resampled(128)
bottom = mpl.colormaps['Blues'].resampled(128)

newcolors = np.vstack((top(np.linspace(0, 1, 128)),
                       bottom(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors, name='OrangeBlue')
```

but I got `AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'resampled'`. It works when I run it on Colab. The code is from matplotlib documentation.

Comment: What Matplotlib version are you using? The `resampled` method was added at version 3.6 https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#colormap-method-for-creating-a-different-lookup-table-size